# Managing JavaScript dependencies with CDN in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Generally speaking, individual JavaScript files that a page uses should be combined into a single filed and minified. To this end, we have an `AssetController.ScriptTag()` that's used like this:

```
<%= ScriptTag
(
    "/js/global.js",
    "/js/accounts.js",
    "/js/googmaps.js"
)%>
```

The output of this method is a single URL that returns a single, minified file from a GET. This worked great until we decided that we needed put our resources like .js and .css files on a CDN. Now, we need to generate these combined, minified JS files at build time, and push the results to the CDN.

How do most people accomplish this--how do they incorporate the generation of these files into their build and deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YUI Compressor for .Net](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) is a popular choice. It allows you to combine and minify Javascript (and CSS is you want).

This article shows, step by step, how to use the YUI compressor during the build process.

http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Studio%20Post-build%20Event%20example&ProjectName=yuicompressor